# How can I tell that userland-proxy has actually been enabled/disabled?

Tags: docker, centos7

I have a CentOS 7.4 VM with Docker 17.05.0-ce, which I am trying to configure as a host for some docker containers.

One of the pieces of guidance given to me is to disable userland proxy.  I've created a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with

```
{
    "userland-proxy": false
}
```

My question - if I set that value to true, what can I look at elsewhere on the system or test (iptables? docker info?) to see the difference that toggling that value will make?

I believe my question stems from not fully understanding what userland-proxy is, despite reading [the networking page](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/#binding-ports).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally leave this option on since there are [unresolved issues when trying to disable it](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14856).

The proxy process runs on the host to forward a port from the host into your container when you publish it. Disabling the userland proxy switches the behavior to run exclusively with iptables rules instead of a userland process.

If the user proxy is enabled, you'll see a `docker-proxy` process launched when you publish a port:

```
$ docker run -p 8888:80 -d --name nginx_test nginx
ee6f2868ed6f4dd2519f8c538cf969552cc36315ae0ce02c5c2939a325541f76

$ ps auxw | grep docker-proxy
root      7366  0.0  0.0 108128  2396 ?        Sl   10:19   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8888 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80

$ docker rm -f nginx_test
nginx_test
```

Comment: Thanks for that Github link - I'll hold off on disabling it just yet!